# Separate a store into two stores by some Id

Tags: extjs, store, extjs6

I have a store with following data

```
[0] Id - 123
    Name - Jim
    CityId - 5

[1] Id - 344
    Name - Rick
    CityId - 5

[2] Id - 67777
    Name - John
    CityId - 4
```

I want to seperate this store into two by cityId so that 1st store will have record for Jim and Rick and second will have John's record.

I can do this by using loop on store but is there any other short way to achieve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did my answer solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.data.Store.html#method-query) provided by sencha for store.As per me this is shortcut method.Please check once is this what you expected.